# Lookup two columns using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a task. For Instance, I have 2 tables. 
Table 1 columns ID, Name
Table 2 columns ID, Name

Data is like in Table 1:

```
                        ID Name
                         1   A
                         2   B
                         3   C
```

Data is like in Table 2:

```
                        ID Name
                         1   D
                         2   B
                         3   E
```

I want to write a SQL query which lookup two tables in both columns. I want to have the count, which records not matching (both columns) with table 2.

Here only one record was matched (2 B). So, I  should get the count 2.

Thanks.

Comment: We have to assume that both tables have an identical number of records, and that each record will match no more than one record in the other table. Then we can consider in these terms: Find the total row count in one of the tables minus the total rows matched across both tables.

Comment: I think what you are actually trying to do is match on ID and see if the name matches, right? This is a trivial join operation.

Comment: @Nick Tables not having identical number of records and each record may repeat in the second table. Instead of count I should get the records which are not matching..

Comment: **Is ID unique in your tables?** I'll get you started - try this: `SELECT T1.Name, T2.Name FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` to count the # of rows in table1 that are not in table2

```
select count(*) from mytable t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.id = t1.id
    and t2.name = t1.name
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked for me. But you wrote "Select 1"  in the SQL why is that used??

Comment: @Nani you could select anything because the select part of an `exists` query doesn't get evaluated. it's just a matter of preference I always use `select 1` for my exists queries.

Comment: Thank you so much @FuzzyTree